# SelectSingleNode in XML for select second element doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have problem to select second node from root element in following example xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <FirstNode>
        <ShowBlahBlah>
        </ShowBlahBlah>
    </FirstNode>
    <SecondNode>
        <ShowBlahBlah>
        </ShowBlahBlah>
    </SecondNode>
</config>
```

and using this C# code to select SecondNode:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sReadXML);
XmlNode sChangesLog = doc.SelectSingleNode("config").SelectSingleNode("//SecondNode").SelectSingleNode("//ShowBlahBlah")
XmlNodeList sChildNodes = sChangesLog.ChildNodes;
```

but it selecting first node and return its value!
how can I fix this problem?

Comment: As an aside, do you have to use XPath and XmlDocument? LINQ to XML tends to make this sort of thing simpler...

Comment: `XmlNode sChangesLog = doc.SelectSingleNode("config/SecondNode/ShowBlahBlah");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `//` at the start of each of your selections - which means ["find descendant nodes starting at the root"](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) (so the context is irrelevant). You could either do things in one step as per Jeffrey's answer, or use relative paths:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("config")
   .SelectSingleNode("SecondNode")
   .SelectSingleNode("ShowBlahBlah")
```

Personally I'd use LINQ to XML instead, if at all possible:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(sReadXml);
var changes = doc.Root.Element("SecondNode").Element("ShowBlahBlah");
```

LINQ to XML is generally a *much* cleaner API than `XmlDocument` et al.